# Ubuntu 12.04 Apache2 Laravel Routes not Working

Tags: php, ubuntu, laravel, apache2, laravel-routing

I have seen other questions like this, but none of the answers have worked for me. I am new to laravel and I am trying to add a new route in app/routes.php. I have followed their example exactly and I am still having trouble. What I have tried:

- Enabling mod_rewrite with `sudo a2enmod rewrite` which did not give me any errors
- Editing my /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/default file
- Restarting apache multiple times with `sudo service apache2 restart`
- Adding this to the bottom of app/routes.php:

  Route::controller(Controller::detect());

Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: What kind of trouble? What happens? Do you get any errors?

Comment: Nothing. I go to 127.0.0.1/users and I get a 404 error. (It should display "Users!" according to the tutorial)

Comment: A Laravel 404 or an Apache 404?

Comment: Apache 404 (. . .127.0.0.1 - - [13/Nov/2013:17:44:06 -0500] "GET /laravel/users HTTP/1.1" 404 500. . .)

Comment: First of all is your virtualhost working? `http://127.0.0.1/` gives you anything at all?

Comment: Yes. I am redirected to index.php.

Comment: Which version of Laravel are you using. `Laravel 4` does not support `Controller::detect()` afaik. would you mind sharing vhost setup and .htaccess/

Comment: Can you post: 1. relevant portions of your `default` vhost file (ServerName, ServerAlias, DocumentRoot), 2. What URL you use in the browser 3. Are you using vagrant or other VM? Thanks!

Comment: OP: I didn't see your earlier response, as you need to ping me using @halfer for me to do so. If you get an Apache 404, it sounds like your `mod_rewrite` config isn't working. Consider adding rewrite logging to see why this is being skipped.

Comment: Is your virtualhost's document root set to `/{path}/{to}/{laravel}/public`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was that laravel wasn't completely installed. It kept failing because my php version was actually outdated. I needed to set it to a more recent php version and then try installing again. For some reason it didn't show any errors. The fix was to delete everything, update php, and start from the beginning.